# SharePoint Workflow REST service POST calls keep returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: 2013, workflow, rest, designer-workflow, web-services

We're trying to call a web service that is hosted on the farm, but it keeps returning a 401 Unauthorized.  We're able to do a GET REST call without issue.  However, even a basic POST call within a workflow returns a 401 Unauthorized.  This only occurs when attempting to do it within a workflow.  When the service is called through AJAX on a page in SharePoint, it executes fine.

Has anyone run into this issue and knows of a possible solution?